# Facebook API Request Dialog not working with Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the following code that logs the user in and displays the "Select Friends for Request" dialog ("apprequests"):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function facebook(){        
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                var access_token = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'apprequests',
                    message: 'Sample Title', 
                    max_recipients:1
                }, function(response){          
                    console.log('OK');
                });
            }
        }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
    }
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <p><a href="javascript:facebook();">Test</a></p>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=0&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The code is working with all major browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, IE11, Safari for IOS, Android browser). Safari (for Mac/PC) is the exception: it's opening the "apprequests" dialog but the dialog comes up empty. If you change the dropdown options (to "Friends to Invite" and then to "All Friends" again) the friend list finally appears.

Any idea how to fix this bug?

Thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, there is a FB bug for this issue, which to my shock has been acknowledged and is listed as "assigned" - linking to Fb bugs seems just as unreliable as their API though. If the link doesn't work, try going to the bugs page and searching for "Safari" - https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/400053553460884/

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen, at least now I know there's not much I can do to solve it. Maybe you should post that info as an answer so I can accept it as valid? All the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is reported bug of [Facebook-API](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/400053553460884/). As [mark wiltse](https://www.facebook.com/mark.wiltse) stated here:

> We have managed to reproduce this issue and it appears to be a valid bug. We are assigning this to the appropriate team.

There is no need to handle it separately for safari. You need to hold this task until the Facebook developer resolves this bug.

**Update:**

The bug is resolved now as per the thread.